# Why do AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds work incorrect in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I don't understand why is there so much space before the end of the screen(photo attached, platform - Android).
It looks like AbsoluteLayout fills not all the space of the screen, but it's not true.Where are also spaces between 'White' buttons(one button should take 20% of the screen; first starts after 4% from the left edge of the screen, second - after 28%: 28% - 4% -20% = 4% free space between buttons)????

Here is xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PokerCalculator.OutsCalculator"
         BackgroundColor="#131313">
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="HotPink">
    <Label Text="Number of outs:"
           FontSize="Medium"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.04,0,0.3,0.18"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional, PositionProportional"  
           BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblOutNumber"
           Text="15"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.35,0,0.18,0.18"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional, PositionProportional"
           BackgroundColor="Azure"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnBack"
            Text="BACK"
            Clicked="btnBack_Clicked"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.7,0,0.28,0.18"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional, PositionProportional"
            BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"/>

    <Button BackgroundColor="White" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.04,0.2,0.20,0.28"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="White"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.28,0.2,0.20,0.28"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="White"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.52,0.2,0.20,0.28"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
    <Button BackgroundColor="White"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.76,0.2,0.20,0.28"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtFQ2.jpg)

[Photo(mockup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAXS6.jpg)

Comment: Well if this is your entire XML file, you aren't closing `<ContentPage>`. Also, looking at the docs, it looks like you need everything to be enclosed in a `<ContentPage.Content>` tag, which sits inside `<ContentPage>`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#proportional-values

Comment: The `<ContentPage.Content>` tags aren't necessary. @SushiHangover, can you edit the post with a mock up of what you're trying to achieve? I have a feeling that your bounds are incorrect, but would need to see what you're going for to be able to help.

Comment: @Andrew Tagged the wrong person

Comment: Apologies, just glanced up and saw your name, didn't notice it was just for the edit.

Comment: @Andrew, I attached a mock up.  You can see how should the spacing look like(the values are proportional).Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could add a design layout of what the whole page is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on here [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80590/absolutelayout-how-to-put-a-stacklayout-30-from-the-top-of-the-page)

Absolute layout proportional does not work/calculated as what you expect. Your intention can be achieved using the `relativelayout` instead.

Lets say that you set X = 0.5 and Width = 0.5.

With your intention you might be expecting the element's X to start from the center and filling the second right half of the absolutelayout bound? **No.**

**The answer** is that the element will be 50% width of the layout bound and be right in the center. Making the X position such as `(0.5 * absolutelayoutWidth) - (0.5 * elementWidth)` (formula is something like this i guess?)

I suggest using `relativelayout`

Answer (score 0):

As a late answer, I've put a nuget package with a fork of AbsoluteLayout but working in a more predictable way.

Install nuget package `SmartMachines.AbsoluteLayout`, add namespace `xmlns:sm="clr-namespace:SmartMachines;assembly=AbsoluteLayout"` and you will have exactly same AbsoluteLayout as native Xamarin, but with expected Proportional alignment behavior.

Hope that will save other people several hours on googling and debugging.